# Margin/width not rending properly on a div element position: fixed; display: table-cell; set

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need my .nav-container position: fixed; so that content doesn't move on scrolling up or down. But doing this creates a gap between the .nav-container and the .page-content, a certain window widths. At these widths there appears to be a small white line between the red background of the .nav-container and the brown border to its right.

If I get rid of the position: fixed; the margins render perfectly but I need that content fixed.

Does anyone know of a work around?

Would it best / possible to leave off the position: fixed; and use Javscript to move all the content in the .nav-container down and up as the window scrolls so that it appears the content is not moving at all?

live link: https://webzume.herokuapp.com/

relevant css:

```
#content {
width: 100%;
display: table; }


#index {
  display: table-row; }

#index .nav-container { 
position: fixed; 
background-color: rgba(222, 89, 58, 0.95);
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-top: 2.5rem;
vertical-align: top;
width: 22.6%;
display: table-cell;}
```

Comment: How about setting the border to the right of the .nav-container instead of left of .page-content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use table formatting for layout! Especially not in combination with position!

Heres how to fix it without the table layout:

1. Remove `display: table` from `#content`
2. Remove `display: table-row` from `#index`
3. Remove `position: fixed` from `#index .nav-container`

On both `#index .nav-container` and `#index .page-content`, do the following:

4. Remove `display: table-cell`
5. Add `float: left`
6. Add `height: 100%`
7. Add `overflow: auto`

Comment: awesome, that totally did it. thank you so much!

Im curious thought, now that I've removed position: fixed, why doesn't my nav scroll? what is producing this "position: fixed-like" behavior of the .nav-container

Comment: Both the right and left sections now take up 100% of screen height. The overflow auto tells it to add a scroll bar if the content overflows. Before the scroll bare belonged to the whole page while now the scroll bar belongs only to the right section. Try setting .page-content height to 50% to see what I mean.

Comment: @Casey Also, if this solves the problem, would you mind marking it as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set page Margin and Padding to zero?

html, body { margin:0; padding:0; }

Comment: Thats not the problem. Did you even check out the live link?